# react child props does not update when sending updated parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a chart component and i'm fetching data from an api through the props data to put in chart but when i'm sending the parent to chart component as props it's not updating the parent state is updated but the child props are not updating and if i log it in

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  console.log(props);
  // it shows updated value but if i do this 
  this.loadData();
}

loadData = () => {
  console.log(props)
  // it's value is old and not updated 
}
```

i have check it in parent the state is updated is and i have a click event in parent when i first click it the parent state changes but chart component props will not change and if i click second time chart component props will the state of first time click state

here's my github repo https://github.com/naveenkash/forex
look in chart component props and pages index.js chart in getting props through index.js

Answer (score 1):

because in componentWillReceiveProps props is reference to new props, they are not yet available in other parts of class, so you should pass them to loadData

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props){
   this.loadData(props);
}

loadData=(props)=>{
   console.log(props)
}
```

Comment: but when my state changes my props should too. that's what i'm doing now passing data in in my loading function

Comment: You are not passing the props value in your example

Comment: @disfatbidge, you really shouldn't force people to look through your code for a simple and narrow question

Answer (score 1):

What Dmitry said is accurate, `this.props` hasn't changed as of `componentWillReceiveProps(props)`.  Therefore when you call `this.loadData()` you're still calling it with the old props.

Note that `componentWillReceiveProps(props)` is 
[unsafe](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

You should use `componentDidUpdate(previousProps)`, where you can call `this.loadData()` and it will execute with updated `this.props`.

Comment: using componentDidUpdate being end up in a loop keeps calling my function in componentDidUpdate

Comment: how componentDidUpdate receive previousProps when it's update won't it get new props

Comment: You need to check `previousProps` against `this.props`-- i.e. if you only want to update if `this.props.ID` changed, then you conditionally call `this.loadData()`: `if (this.props.ID === prevProps.ID) { return; }`.  And since `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` is called AFTER an update,  you have the new props in `this.props`.  So to get new props you call `this.props` and to get previous props you call `prevProps`.

Answer (score 0):

It's js scope issue not react event lift cycle issue, considering changing the code as below:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  console.log(props);
  // it shows updated value but if i do this 
  this.loadData(props);
}

loadData = (newProps) => {
  console.log(newProps)
  // it's value is old and not updated 
}
```